# Планировщик задач на Java

Tags: java

**Здравствуйте! Нужно создать "Планировщик задач на Java".**
Мы с другом надумали:

1. Все задачи (время,дата,название,описание)будут работать с базой данных(mysql)
2. Каждую минуту программа будет проверять или сверять время и дату в системе с базой данных
3. Без многопоточности не обойтись мы так поняли .

---

Подскажите пожалуйста , получится ли , если нет то ваши варианты .

Comment: Все получится! Будут конкретные вопросы — заходите, спрашивайте.

Comment: [Этот велосипед](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) уже давно изобрели.

Comment: Зачем вам с другом многопоточность?

Answer (score 1):

1. Сканируете БД
2. Находите **ближайшее** событие
3. Считаете сколько до него осталось времени и засыпаете на это время
4. После пробуждения выполняете это событие и переходите к п.1
5. При модификации БД просыпаетесь досрочно и переходите к п.1